# Numbers: Make numbers negative

Tags: numbers

In Numbers, how can I convert a number to negative.

E.g.

```
200
233
186
```

Becomes

```
-200 
-233 
-186
```

In Excel, you can use tools like Paste Special, but these don't exist in Numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workaround is to create a column with formulas like "=-1 * A1", then copy and "Paste Formula Results" (⇧⌘V).  But I'm sure there are better solutions.

Answer (score 3):

It would be awkward, might not be [worth the time](https://xkcd.com/1205/), but you would need to program this in [automator using numbers hooks for automation](http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/iwork/numbers/services-support.html) / accessibility. That way you could make a service to swap the sign of whatever is selected.

Short term, you'd manually change each or set up a function to calculate the negative of the selection and then paste the values over the source.

This is one of the features that just isn't baked into Numbers (yet).